# How to prevent multiple network requests with reactive switchmap

Tags: angular, angularfire2, rxjs6

I am doing a request on my service.ts and subscribing to it in a component.

All is working as I would expect, but it results in many request to the network. How can I write this better to prevent this?

```
 getDeal(id: string){
    const item: AngularFirestoreCollection<Deal> = this._afs.collection(`deals`,
    (ref) => ref.where(`id`, '==', id));
    return item.valueChanges().pipe(
     // take(1),
      map(arr => {
        return arr;
    }),
      switchMap(arr => {
        const userObservables = arr.map(deal => this._afs.doc(`users/${deal.customerId}`).valueChanges()
          );
         return combineLatest(...userObservables)
            .pipe(
              map((...eusers) => {
                arr.forEach((deal, index) => {
                  deal['customer_username'] =  eusers[0][index].displayName.username;
                  deal['customer_avatar'] = eusers[0][index].photoURL;

              });
              return arr;
            })
            );
      }),
      switchMap(arr => {
        const userObservables = arr.map(deal => this._afs.doc(`users/${deal.dealerId}`).valueChanges()
          );
         return combineLatest(...userObservables)
            .pipe(
              map((...eusers) => {
                arr.forEach((deal, index) => {
                  deal['dealer_username'] =  eusers[0][index].displayName.username;
                  deal['dealer_avatar'] = eusers[0][index].photoURL;
              });

              return arr;
            })
            );
      }),
      share()
  );

  }
```

In the component I do a subscribe ..

```
this.subDeal = this._service.getDeal(id).subscribe((deal) => {
console.log(deal) // This should log just once, but it logs multiple times
}):
```

How to prevent the multiple network request?

Comment: is your service a singleton?

Comment: Not it's not! Can that be the problem?

Comment: could be, if your service is not a singleton and injected multiple times, every time it is declared it will fire the http request one time.

Comment: I doubt it is!. but would keep researching. Thanks